# Help in deciding hardware for web server

Tags: hardware, webserver

I want set up a local web server to be used in my office. It will be made online in future (~1 or 2 years) but for now it is locally used. I have gone through some tutorials ([here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-setup-a-dedicated-web-server-for-free/)) to set up a LAMP web server. The usage is expected to be as follows

- Used for: Drupal Web Applications
- Current Users: 15
- Prospected Users (in a year): 60 (some over internet)
- Files upload/download: min. 10 files daily per user
- I do need constant back of all my data on server

What should be the server hardware specifications for my scenario? Do I really need to have SSD for fast IO operations or should I go for RAID? How much RAM? What about network card? Please it would be really helpful if anyone can point to a articles that explains these specifics.

Comment: Raspberry PI will do fine...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about hardware recomendations.

Comment: @alvar sorry I asked but It was specific to Ubuntu context as Ubuntu can run good on low end machines.

Comment: You may want to ask this on [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/) It's off topic here sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

15-60 users — even concurrently, which I assume this isn't — is not a busy site. You could get away with low-end hardware. If you've got a spare box in the office, that would do. You could probably even host it in a virtual machine on one of the existing desktops.

I would be against *purchasing* anything until you've got some sort of idea how the setup actually runs. Every website is different. How much they churn the database and filesystem differs. How much RAM they use differs. Get it running *somewhere* and see where the bottlenecks are.

The main problem is the backup process. It's not automatic and requires you to know what you're doing (you'll want to go through a dry and ideally a wet run before a real crash). They'll need to be stored off the server, ideally off-site. What happens if a meteor hits? What happens if you're standing next to the server when a meteor hits you both? Are there instructions on how to restore to new hardware? Is this all secure?

There's also a question about maintenance. You set this up and you're typically responsible for its uptime. It's not just software, hardware does blow up every so often. And the power consumption. And if you're making this internet-accessible, your upstream bandwidth at the office might not suffice.

I'd personally be looking to test locally but deploy to an off-site third party. There are thousands of VPS hosts (Linode, Digital Ocean, etc) that won't charge you more than $10-20 a month for a regularly backed-up service.

And then there's the software maintainance. If you're using popular open source software (like Drupal), the most important thing is keeping the thing updated. If you don't, your server will be compromised. That most commonly means hosting crapware to infect other people, send spam... But if can also mean the wholesale theft of customer data.

If you don't know what you're doing, and can't afford to learn, don't host stuff on the internet. Pay somebody to manage it for you. This typically means either paying for a website hosting account (often cheaper than VPS access) or paying for a managed server (typically +~$100/month on top of the hardware lease). They come with support and it's often worth it just for the peace of mind.

Comment: My main concern is file upload/download which I think is faster locally. So how about going local right away and in future host it somewhere when connecting internet users (satisfy security/hardware needs)?

Comment: As I'm trying to get across, you can test almost every aspect of every type of solution without spending much money. You can test a local server with a VM or by repurposing an unused machine... Or online with a VPS. See what works for you.